# Python set datetime to UTC timezone

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone

I have an event I would like to trigger in Python, every weekend between Friday morning and Sunday morning.

I have wrote some code that works on my local environment but I'm afraid when deployed to production, the date time will be localised and the trigger will be incorrect.
Ideally I would like everything to be synced to UTC, here's my attempt - I'd like to see if it's correct and if anyone has feedback on how to make it cleaner.

(The code works for me but I'm in the correct timezone anyway :) )

```
from datetime import datetime
def eventTrigger():
    if((datetime.weekday(datetime.today()) == 4) and (datetime.now().utcnow.hour) > 9):
        return True
    elif ((datetime.weekday(datetime.today()) == 6) and (datetime.now().utcnow.hour) < 10):
        return True
    elif (datetime.weekday(datetime.today()) == 5):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I tried reading the datetime documentation but it's pretty confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Datetimes and timezones are confusing, it's good you're making sure to be deliberate here.

First, library `pytz` can help

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
```

Then, you can define `today` and `now` variables, to be reliably UTC, at the top of your `eventTrigger()` with:

```
now_utc   = datetime.now(pytz.utc) 
today_utc = now_utc.date()
```

Comment: Great, thank you!
Just as a clarification, what's the difference between using:
    datetime.now(pytz.utc)
and:
    datetime.now().utcnow.hour

Comment: have you run both and compared the outputs?

Comment: I have now, there is a syntax error in: datetime.now().utcnow.hour which only appeared when I tested for the event...

I'm sure I checked that before asking the question. Much appreciated Max :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to do this with the Python 3 standard library and without external dependency on `pytz`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

now_utc = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
today_utc = now_utc.date()
```

Comment: This doesn't works in Python 2.x. I know Python 2.x is dead! But, but is useful to know about it to avoid time wasting!

Comment: @Andre Carneiro I added the major Python version this answer works with.